# Excel "SEARCH" formula delivering odd results

Tags: excel-formula

I am working on a list of file locations numbering about 25k.  Out of this bulk of locations, I need to filter out a subset of the locations for a third party.  This list is 2k file locations.  I am looking for a method to determine which locations in the larger list match the smaller list.  Manually filtering this number of files is daunting and prone to errors.

At this time, the formula matches some files that are in both, but also matches files that are in the larger list but cannot be found in the smaller list.

This is the formula I am using.
<> and [] denote values to fill in, not the literal values used.

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(!A:A,[Cell_Value]))

It is entirely possible, and expected, to have multiple locations in the same file in the . I am  concerned with filtering out the file locations that do not match the  for this task.

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH([Cell_Value],A:A,0))`

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Craner pointed in his comment, you can use:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH([Cell_Value],A:A,0))
```

See working example:

[image]